Main authorship of research paper
I wanted to publish a research paper under my own name for some educational reasons. Now I was introduced to one of these research conferences cum publications called as CVPR for computer vision domain. This suggestion was made by my Head of Department.
My HOD wants me to do the entire work from finding appropriate topic to writing the full paper in proper format. The reasons being

Me being vastly interested in this field and lack of candidates who are willing to take up this task.
My HOD does not have any knowledge about computer vision domain.

The issue is my HOD is avoiding sharing me the complete paper publication process beforehand and insisting me to submit the complete paper on official email. My concern is that he will publish it as him being the main author and me being the co-author. I am stuck between completing the paper, taking appropriate credits for the work and also not crossing college department in the process as I need their help for future purposes.
Is there any solution to this and does a faculty member need to be the part of paper publication process?

I don't think I understood your problem. Do you not have access to the whole paper? What is the paper publication process you are talking about? Is it the submission of the paper? CVPR deadlines are usually in the middle of the year. So, as far as I know, there won't be any submission process happening for now.

Why don't you trust him?

Maybe you can explain what you mean by "official email" as the obvious interpretation is that you use your work email address when you submit.  This is standard and I don't see the risk.

Information on how to submit papers to CVPR is on the website, the submission system is OpenReview, its public information, not a secret, did you try to find this information? Also the next submission cycle is next year, in around 10 months from now.

I am also confused.
